# Rows with different records count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this query

```
SELECT    COUNT(RequestNo), RequestNo
FROM      dbo.RequestInfo283
WHERE     CustomerNo='0015948490'
GROUP BY  RequestNo
```

The query result

```
Count     | RequestNo
-------------------
1         |9325652313
2         |9560989759
1         |9561289527
2         |9569954000
2         |9667504620
```

As you see, the above query result is just for a customer and RequestNo counts are different . I want a query which give me all `customerNo`(not only one customerNo) which their `COUNT(RequestNo)` are different.
honestly I have no idea how to write it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT CustomerNo
FROM (SELECT CustomerNo, RequestNo, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM dbo.RequestInfo283 
      GROUP BY CustomerNo, RequestNo
     ) cr
GROUP BY CustomerNo
HAVING MIN(cnt) <> MAX(cnt);
```